# Parsing words from a xml file

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file called "interview.xml" that looks like this:

```
<SpeechSegment spkid="S0">
    <Word dur="0.22" stime="0.44">oh</Word>
    <Word dur="0.27" stime="1.67">bedankt</Word>
    <Word dur="0.3" stime="2.03">voor</Word>
    <Word dur="0.53" stime="2.61">deelname</Word>
    <Word dur="0.22" stime="3.15">aan</Word>
    <Word dur="0.23" stime="3.39">de</Word>
    <Word dur="0.14" stime="6.15">want</Word>
    <Word dur="0.07" stime="6.29">ik</Word>
    <Word dur="0.09" stime="6.36">wil</Word>
    <Word dur="0.06" stime="6.45">je</Word>
    <Word dur="0.42" stime="6.51">graag</Word>
    <Word dur="0.2" stime="7.52">en</Word>
</SpeechSegment>
```

What I would like to do now is parse all the words from this segment, so I want to create a list like `["oh", "bedankt", "voor", etc...]`

I tried this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('Interview_short.xml').getroot()

for atype in e.findall('type'):
    print(atype.get('word'))
```

But this does not give me the output I am looking for. Any thoughts what adjustments I should make?

Comment: You have to access the xml tag content with elements.text

Comment: So when you have your SpeechSegment element, with e.findall('SpeechSegment') for example and than comparing against the attribute with element.attrib["spkid"] == "S0", you do something like wordlist=[ word.text for word in SS]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Solution:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
required_list = [child.text for child in root]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why `findall('type')` while the XML doesn't contain any `<type>` element. According to the XML posted, it should've been `findall('Word')`. Here is a minimal but complete codes for demo :

```
raw = '''<SpeechSegment spkid="S0">
    <Word dur="0.22" stime="0.44">oh</Word>
    <Word dur="0.27" stime="1.67">bedankt</Word>
    <Word dur="0.3" stime="2.03">voor</Word>
    <Word dur="0.53" stime="2.61">deelname</Word>
    <Word dur="0.22" stime="3.15">aan</Word>
    <Word dur="0.23" stime="3.39">de</Word>
    <Word dur="0.14" stime="6.15">want</Word>
    <Word dur="0.07" stime="6.29">ik</Word>
    <Word dur="0.09" stime="6.36">wil</Word>
    <Word dur="0.06" stime="6.45">je</Word>
    <Word dur="0.42" stime="6.51">graag</Word>
    <Word dur="0.2" stime="7.52">en</Word>
</SpeechSegment>'''

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(raw)
result = [word.text for word in root.findall('Word')]
print result
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/805771)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
['oh', 'bedankt', 'voor', 'deelname', 'aan', 'de', 'want', 'ik', 'wil', 'je', 'graag', 'en']
```

Comment: Many thanks for your elaborated answer. The last issue I have is replicating the data you have from loading it from an actual xml file. Now if have the exact same data in an xml file which i try to import by: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
raw2 = ET.parse('Interview_short.xml') but this gives me: <xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x0000000001EC7DD8> ... Any thoughts?

Comment: `root = raw2.getroot()` and the rest should be the same